PyFlink job not getting submitted
I am running my flink jobs in a docker container which is in an ec2 instance.I have written a pyflink job and trying to submit it via the following command:-
./bin/flink run -d --python Jobs/test.py.
But the job is neither getting submitted nor throwing an error as it remains blank. My python code is as follows:-
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.common.serialization import SimpleStringSchema
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer

def main():
    # Create a StreamExecutionEnvironment
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib/flink-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar","file:///opt/flink/lib/flink--connector-kafka-clients-3.7.0.jar>

    # Define the Kafka source properties
    kafka_source_properties = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'servers are mentioned',
        'group.id': 'flink-alert-tokenizer',
        'key.deserializer': 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer',
        'value.deserializer': 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer',
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
    }
 
    # Create a Kafka consumer
    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='servers are mentioned',
        topic name='kafka_topic'
        deserialization_schema=SimpleStringSchema(),
        properties=kafka_source_properties
    )

    # Add the Kafka consumer as the data source
    data_stream = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)

    # Print the data to the standard output
    data_stream.print()

    # Execute the Flink streaming job
    env.execute("PyFlink Kafka Consumer Example")
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I would like to know the reason as to why the job isn't getting submitted and fix the issue.
